# Ignore features outside the area of interest in QGIS for an ArcGIS Feature Service layer

Tags: qgis, feature-service

I have layers in ArcGIS Feature Service format in my map that have more than 100,000 features. I am not editing them but just using them as a reference. I work only in a particular small area at one time. I can't open the attribute table for these files, because they have thousands of features.

Is there a way to set a filter in a QGIS project to ignore everything that is outside a particular area, so that the map is faster, and I can open the attribute table. If the filter is not possible, then only open the attribute table for selected features.

Comment: esriGeometryEnvelope will be required example http://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Specialty/ESRI_StateCityHighway_USA/MapServer/1/query?text=&geometry=-125.4%2C35.2%2C-118.7%2C43.8&geometryType=esriGeometryEnvelope&inSR=&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&relationParam=&objectIds=&where=&time=&returnCountOnly=false&returnIdsOnly=false&returnGeometry=true&maxAllowableOffset=&outSR=&outFields=&f=pjson